# Official SW gaming aids compatibility with SWD

Tags: savage-worlds

Peginc.com has a number of interesting and rather helpful-looking gaming aids (for a newbie SWD GM) available for free download, such as the *[Training Wheels Character Sheet](https://www.peginc.com/freebies/SWcore/SWEX_TrainingWheelsCS.pdf)* and the *[GM Screen Insert / Reference Info](https://www.peginc.com/freebies/SWcore/explorersgmscreen.pdf)*. Are these (especially these two) compatible with Savage Worlds Deluxe, or are there minor but crucial differences, because of these being for an earlier edition? (One thing I've noticed - because SWD explicitly mentions it - is the presence/removal of Guts.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of the two documents you have listed have been updated for Savage Worlds Deluxe. In addition to the Guts skill, there are a number of additions to the rules that are missing from both documents, including the Push manoeuvre, Rapid Attack, options for attacking with improvised weapons and the updated incapacitation rules.

All in all though the differences are small and you could probably still use them. However, for the GM screen a better option is the fan-made update available [here](http://savagepedia.wikispaces.com/file/view/swdeluxe-gm-screen.pdf).